# vector 2次元配列で任意の行にpush_backできますか？

Tags: c++, rad-studio

vector 2次元配列で任意の縦列にpush_backできますか？

```
vector<string> v;

v.at(5).push_back("test");
```

vectorで宣言したvの5行目の0番地目に”test”という文字列を代入したかったので、このようなプログラムを実行してみたところ、次のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
[bcc32c エラー] Unit2.cpp(44): cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char' with an lvalue of type 'const char [5]'
  xstring(1899): passing argument to parameter '_Ch' here
```

Comment: 2次元の vector だとすれば宣言は `vector<vector<string> > v(6, vector<string>(2));` などの様になるのではないでしょうか(6行2列の場合)。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。
vector<string> v[6][2];

この宣言は上と同じ6行2列の2次元vectorにはならないのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、それは `vector<string>` を要素とする2次元**配列**になります。なので、`v[5][0].push_back("test");` などとするのは問題ありませんが、`v[5].push_back("test");` はコンパイルエラーになります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector<string>` は二次元配列ではないし
`vector::push_back()` は「新たな要素を末尾に追加する」のであって、任意の場所に追加するわけではないので、

答えは **できません** なわけですが

> vectorで宣言したvの5行目の0番地目

という文言から見ると `vector<string>` が何をどう保持しているのか理解不足のように思われます。特に 0番地目 なる文言が意味不明。やりたいことは単に

```
v[4]="test"; // あるいは v[4]=string("test"); なり v.at(4)="test";
```

で良いのではないっすか？ `v[5]` だと要素は６番目っす。もし仮に `v[4]` がまだ無いのであれば事前に `v.resize(5);` なりなんなりが必要。

真にやりたいことが @nordsynth 氏自身よくわかっていないに１票。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。
`
vector<string> v[6];

v[5][0] = "test02";
`
このコードでビルド成功しました。vの数は要素というのですね。

Comment: `vector<string> v[6];` なら `string` の二次元配列と呼んでよいです。が、コメント欄提示コードでは動かないはず。それだけだと `v[5]`  の要素数は０だから。単純配列と `vector` はメモリ上配置が若干違うので一度絵でもかいてみると理解が進んで吉かと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。宣言の仕方でコードのエラーの出方が違ったので焦ったのですが、その辺が関係しているのですね（＾＾；